# Hosting .net core and creating managed instances

Tags: .net-core, interop, unmanaged, managed, coreclr

I'm attempting to load a .net core library in a native application with the intention of creating an instance of a managed object

I've followed Microsoft's recommendation to use hostfxr to load the .netcore 3+ library

Using the NativeHost.vs/DotNetLib sample, I've been able to call a native static method.

I would like to create a managed object and call methods on it, ideally creating a type library so that I can handle the interop between native and managed parts of the application.

This was the way we did it with the full .net framework, but there doesn't seem to be any analogue to

**mscoree.CLRCreateInstance**

with hostfxr.

Using CoreClrHost is only recommended for < .net core 3.0

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

What I am attempting to do is not possible at this stage. There is no "embedding API" for .net core

As per Vitek Karas comment here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/3676

> The load_assembly_and_get_function_pointer is not meant as a
>   replacement for a low level so called "embedding" API - which would
>   let you work with managed objects/methods from native code in a
>   generic manner. It is meant to provide a robust way to initialize the
>   runtime and get a way to call into managed code.
>
> We expect people to use this functionality to either make a single (or
>   few) calls to managed code, or to build their own "interop" on top.
>   The problem with allowing to create a native function pointer to any
>   method is that if the method's signature is not super simple, there's
>   no way to customize the marshaling. For example if the method would
>   take a string argument, there would be no way to specify which
>   encoding should be exposed to the native code... and so on.
>
> The "embedding API" which would allow native code to have much greater
>   control over the communication with managed is something we are
>   considering for the future.
>
> We did consider exposing the coreclr hosting directly (from the new
>   functionality), but it creates some non-trivial problems with lifetime
>   management. And also going forward it would be really tricky to do
>   this in a consistent way if the runtime is actually Mono.